# how to lock a table in MySQL but not affect other tables

Tags: mysql

I want to lock a table in MySQL for the purpose that other processes cannot access that table while I have it locked.

The MySQL docs says this about `LOCK TABLES` command:

MySQL enables client sessions to acquire table locks explicitly for the purpose of cooperating with other sessions for access to tables, or to prevent other sessions from modifying tables during periods when a session requires exclusive access to them.

Good, so I try to do

```
mysql>LOCK TABLES foo WRITE;
```

and I can check that other processes cannot then access `foo`.

The problem is that *I* cannot access other tables.  The documentation says:

A session that requires locks must acquire all the locks that it needs in a single LOCK TABLES statement. While the locks thus obtained are held, the session can access only the locked tables

This is very strange.  Why am I forced to also lock other tables.  I only want to prevent others from accessing `foo`.  I do not want to lock anything else, I just want to access other tables as normal.

How to just lock one table and not change anything about other tables??

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/). Why do you want “other processes cannot access that table ”?

Comment: locking entire tables generally isn't necessary anymore since most everyone uses innodb and that supports row-level locks.

Comment: @DourHighArch ???  this is the normal usage of "mutual exclusion" in software engineering - you have multiple processes running, there is some resource, that must be accessed atomically, so you have some sort of lock, you lock it from one process, then while this process has it locked, other processes cannot do the same

Comment: @MarcB in my situation, "row-level" locks is not enough.  I MUST ensure this one table is accessed only by one process at a time.  I DO NOT want to change anything at all about all the other tables, which are completely independent and unrelated to this one.

Comment: `select * from foo for update`? that'll effectively lock it.

Comment: @MarcB not sure what you mean - `select * from foo for update` does not "lock" anything for me, it just prints the whole table and exits

Comment: @MarkGaleck, if you start a transaction, and use SELECT FOR UPDATE, it will lock all rows matched by the SELECT. Leave the transaction uncommitted while you do other work. (You're using InnoDB, right?)

Comment: @BillKarwin  I am not sure what you mean by "uncommitted".  If I do "SELECT FOR UPDATE" like I said, the whole table is printed and the command exists.  No locking occurs.  I have no clue what storage engine I am using.  Why would that matter.  The documentation for MySQL LOCK TABLE, does not say anything about any storage engine dependency.

Comment: MySql already enforces mutual exclusion at the row and table level through transactions. If there is something you think it is not doing, please explain.

Answer (score 0):

Being that this `LOCK TABLES` feature behaves in this (strange in my opinion) way, one way to handle this, is not use this process for anything else.  That is, spawn a process just to lock this table, access this table, and unlock it.  Use other processes to access other tables - the restriction to not be able to access other tables is not *global* as such, it is just limited to that one process.

After that, of course, I still have to synchronize control flow between the multiple processes I just created.  But that is out of MYSql, I can just use whatever programming language I am using, which has such facilities.

I guess another way, would be to create a new database and put that one table in the new database.

Answer (score 0):

LOCK TABLES has no storage engine dependency, because it is handled by the SQL layer, above the storage engine layer. Row locks are handled within the InnoDB storage engine.

Sorry that MySQL's architecture is so complex. This is the advantage and the disadvantage of supporting multiple storage engines. Most RDBMS products don't have this capability, so all storage features appear more integrated into the rest of the functionality. In MySQL, the code for storage engines is independent from the storage-independent code, and some features may be implemented with certain storage engines.

Transactions are a good example. InnoDB supports transactions, and this defines the scope for InnoDB locking. When the transaction ends, all InnoDB-managed locks are released.

By default, the MySQL client tool and most programming interfaces operate in "autocommit" mode. So every SQL statement starts a new transaction and automatically commits it when the query finishes.

But you can control when transactions start and finish.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/commit.html